# esp32 not recognising on macOS

Tags: macos-sierra

I am trying to flash micropython on Esp32. But when I plug-in the ESP32 into Mac, its doesn't recognize on port /dev/tty*

I did install the drivers CP210x USB to UART Bridge VCP Drivers from https://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers

I am on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Any idea what wrong here ?

Answer (score -1):

Have you seen [this article](http://thingsmatic.com/2017/08/07/using-ch340-devices-with-osx/)? Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.